# How to store number of clicks if viewmodel keeps restarting?

Tags: android, kotlin

I basically have this function that validates the click of the user:

```
   this.btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.responsePictures.observeForever {
                manageResponse(it)
            }
            clickcount += 1
            if (clickcount == 3) {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.errorComprovante)
            }

        }
```

The observer is responsible for managing the response of the service. So if the users clicks the button 3 times and it doesn't get any success response, it goes to the errorComprovante.
The problem is that if i use this code with the observer, it simply doesn't work.

Is there a way i can store the number of clicks so that it doesn't get lost? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Further Reading on Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Store the data in Shared Preferences.

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("count", clickCounter);
editor.commit();
```

Then get the data from the preferences using
`sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i think you meant editor.puInt. Also i would like to know if the value of sharedPreferences in a if statement to check the number of clicks.

Comment: Yeah yeah i'll change it .. And yes you can use it just like a normal variable.I'll make the answer a bit more elaborate. make sure to accept the answer if it helps you.:)

Comment: For some reason i put the clickcount++ inside the observer and now it's working. But i think sharedPreferences could work too.

Comment: Yeah, you're right that's a much better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value in a hidden field, that way it would be kept on the client side and would stay as long the the page is not re-rendered.

Comment: Can you give an example please? I think i never used such thing

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences, database, files.  All ways to persist data.